# Can't Port Forward a Bukkit Minecraft Server

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I setup a [Bukkit Server](https://bukkit.org/) and port forward on my router. I am 200% sure the LAN IP is correctly input (`192.168.0.101`) and port is `25565`. The server also kicks up just fine, but the problem is I can't connect from ANYWHERE ELSE other than my own LAN. The router is a TP-Link TL-WR720N just in case anyone needs it.

Here's some additional information:

1. Router configuration screenshot:

[image: Router configs]

2. Server properties:

   ```
   server-port=25565;
   server-ip=192.168.0.100;
   spawn-npcs=true;
   allow-flight=false;
   level-name=world;
   view-distance=10;
   resource-pack=;
   spawn-animals=true;
   white-list=false;
   generate-structures=true;
   online-mode=false;
   ```
3. `ipconfig` info:

   ```
   Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 2:

   ipv4 address: 192.168.0.101
   ```

Comment: Stupid question, have you tried rebooting the router since the Firewall change? You are using [your public IP](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip) to connect from the world? When the connection fails, what is the error message? Refused? Time-Out? Might there be anything in the server config that is refusing WAN connections?

Comment: I am assuring everyone that I have rebooted the router a million times, and the error message is connection refused. And yes I did use my public IP to connect from the world. There's also an exception in the firewall for the server. If you need the server config, I have attached it to the question description. And no, no other devices are connected to my network.

Comment: Remove the IP binding on the server config. Leave it blank that way it will listen to any IP.

Comment: Did someone who's not within your network try to connect?

Comment: Yes I tried it on three other PCs on my network through localhost:25565 and just localhost, and both work just fine. Only people outside my network can't join........

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

Your ipv4 is: 192.168.0.101

the server.properties shows this:

```
server-port=25565;
server-ip=192.168.0.100;
spawn-npcs=true;
allow-flight=false;
level-name=world;
view-distance=10;
resource-pack=;
spawn-animals=true;
white-list=false;
generate-structures=true;
online-mode=false;
```

See the problem? No?

server-ip=**192.168.0.100**;

192.168.0.100 is not the same as 192.168.0.101 ;)